# python question for random math question generator

Tags: python

i cant make the list for the result of the answer that is typed in. i wanted to make a list so it shows all the result i typed in but the list is not showing. can anyone help me with the list and make my code working ?
this is the code

````
answerthatistyped = []

def asknumber():
    while (1):
        try:
            answer = int(input("enter the correct number"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("incorrect input")
            continue
        return answer
def askquestion():
    number_1 = random.randint(1,5)
    number_2 = random.randint(1,5)

    print("what is" ,number_1,"+",number_2,)

    result = asknumber()
    list_result = int(result) - 0
    answer_that_is_typed.append(listresult)
    if result == number_1 + number_2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

amount = 6
correct = 0
for i in range(amount):
    correct += askquestion()

print("You got %d correct out of %d" % (correct, amount))
print(answerthatistyped)```
````

Comment: There's a typo in your code `list_result` or `listresult`?

Comment: `return answer` this `Code is unreachable` place outside of `except block`

Comment: `int(result) - 0` is the same as just `result`. Why do you do that?

Comment: @ExplooreX ITYM place it out of `while` loop.

Comment: instead of `result == number_1 + number_2` for correct logic `result != number_1 + number_2`

Comment: interchange last `2 line` for perfect output

Answer (score 0):

```
answerthatistyped.append(listresult)
```

you typed "**answer_that_is_typed**" instead "**answerthatistyped**"

Answer (score 0):

essentially i think there is a typo, maybe you meant `list_result` instead of `listresult`. However as you are using python i'd like to suggest you a more "pythonic" way to reach your solution:

```
answerthatistyped = []

def asknumber():
    while True:
        try:
            answer = int(input("enter the correct number"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("incorrect input")
            continue
        return answer
def askquestion():
    number_1 = random.randint(1,5)
    number_2 = random.randint(1,5)

    print(f"what is {number_1} + {number_2}")

    result = asknumber()
    answer_that_is_typed.append(int(result))
    return not bool(result == number_1 + number_2)
```

Comment: It still won't be able to reach the `return answer` code because the `return` statement is inside `while` and you have used `break`

Comment: @ExplooreX what's the difference between `a != b` and `not (a == b)`? I always prefer to never use `!=` in python, just seems less pythonic than `not` keyword

Comment: @Giuppox both are the same result

Comment: @Giuppox sorry I comment for your fist edit  :)